# command line replacement with new value not working

Tags: perl

I am very new to the perl 
         Here is what I am   doing I have input line like this
         I want to substitute the value of each line that matches with the
         string by passing variable name,variable value and replace value 
         as input argument through command line

```
     input_data:
     total_sum  0x0C    Uint8,unsigned char     
     num     0x0D   Uint8,unsigned char     
     max    0x4A    Uint8,unsigned char     
     padd   0x00    Uint8,unsigned char     
     ideal  0x01    Uint16, unsigned short
     min    0xffdd7f Uint16, unsigned short
```

expected output:

```
     1.total_sum    0x0C    Uint8,unsigned char  //change 0x0B with 0x0C
     2.also if the string conation Uin16 then I need to pad 0x00 as i 
        want to read only one byte at a time
        for e.g ideal should be pad with (0x00,0x01)
     3.also if the string contain value more than one byte then i need 
        to split with 1 byte each
        for e.g oxffdd7f should be (0x0ff,0xdd,0x7f)
```

Code:

```
    #! /usr/bin/env perl

     use strict;
     use warnings;
     # input variable pass as a input argument
     my $variable_name =shift @ARGV;
     # variable value pass as a input argument
     my $variable_value =shift @ARGV;
     #variable value need to be replaced with new value 
     my $Replacement_var = shift @ARGV;
     # Name of the file the data is in
     my $input_filename  = 'my_input.txt';
     # Name of the file you want to dump the output to
     my $output_filename = 'my_output.txt';

     open my $input_fh, "<", $input_filename or die $!; 
     my @array;   
     while (my $eachline = <$input_fh>)
     {
     if ($eachline=~/^$variable_name/ and /$variable_value/)
        {
         $eachline=s/$variable_value/$Replacement_var/ ;
        }
        #here  extracting only hex values from each line
        while ($eachline =~ m/(0x(?:[0-9]|[A-f])+)/gi)  
        {
          push @array, $1;
        }
     }

     close $input_fh;
     open my $output_fh, ">", $output_filename or die $!;
     print {$output_fh} join(", ", @array);
```

I am checking variable name and value then replace variable value 
         with  new one but replace is not happening (field_ind 0x0B->0x0C)
         please help me where I am doing mistake.

Answer (score 4):

```
$eachline=~/^$variable_name/ and /$variable_value/
```

should be

```
$eachline=~/^$variable_name/ and $eachline=~/$variable_value/
```

When the bind operator (`=~`) is not used explicitly to the left side of a regular expression, Perl implicitly binds it to the `$_` variable.

---

You also want to use the bind operator in another place and say

```
$eachline =~ s/$variable_value/$Replacement_var/ ;
```

rather than

```
$eachline = s/$variable_value/$Replacement_var/ ;
```

Comment: I have tried to replace total_sum  0x0C-->0xE  but its not working replace all the value with 0x00

Comment: its not replace with 0x00 actually replacement is not happening.